# Using Vim as an HTML editor

Tags: html, vim, editor, notepad++

You know how Notepad++ has this feature that when you click on a tag (say ) it automatically highlights the ending tag () as well? What's it called? And how do you tweak Vim to have this feature as well?

And any more ways you can turn Vim into a powerful and efficient HTML editor?

Comment: matchit seems to work, but is there a way of highlighting the matching tags rather than typing %? Because typing % is more troublesome plus it's not obvious when there're a LOT of similar tags nested under one another.

Answer (score 15):

I do all of my HTML editing in vim.  The three plugins I find most helpful for editing HTML and XML in vim are matchit, surround, and [allml](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896).

Matchit will allow you to jump to the start/end tag with '%'.  Surround allows you to easily add, delete, and change the surrounding tags.  Allml provides you with a great set of mappings for editing (X)HTML and XML.

Comment: allml has been renamed to [ragtag](https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag/blob/master/doc/ragtag.txt)

Answer (score 7):

wrap selected text with tags:

```
    function! VisualTagsWrap()
        if !exists('g:tags_to_wrap')
            let g:tags_to_wrap=[]
        endif
        let g:tags_to_wrap=split(input('space separated tags to wrap block: ', join(g:tags_to_wrap, ' ')), '\s\+')
        if len(g:tags_to_wrap)>0
            execute 'normal! `>a</'.join(reverse(g:tags_to_wrap), '></').'>'
            execute 'normal! `<i<'.join(reverse(g:tags_to_wrap), '><').'>'
        endif
    endfunction


vnoremap <silent>,w <ESC>:call VisualTagsWrap()<CR>
```

highlight closing bracket for tags:

```
set matchpairs+=<:>
```

dummy text (type "lorem" in insert mode):

```
inoreabbrev lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
```

Comment: Hi so where do these code go? Sorry but I'm a noob VIM-er so you have to put it really clearly! :(

Comment: put that code into your .vimrc. use ,w in select mode to wrap text, use % to switch between tag's brackets

Comment: Just added this to my vimrc today. I like it. Now all I need is something like `vi<` that visual selects in between a pair of tags.

Comment: @asfallows use `cit` for change in tag, for example haha (`vit` also works)

Answer (score 4):

**To match tags:**

Have a look at [matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) plugin. Vim 6 onwards matchit.vim is packaged with standard distribution. To install matchit, read `:help matchit-install`.

Make sure `filetype plugin on` is in vimrc.

Once installed, use `%` to match the start/end tag. `:help matchit-intro` for more help.

Comment: Really? It's not inside, I'm running 7.2, I gotta install it seperately.

Comment: Yes. At least it was the case with vim 7.2 which came with Cygwin and Ubuntu Jaunty.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [this link](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=188640)

it describes a bug report and the patch(es) which may fix it.

```
set matchpairs+=<:>
set showmatch
set matchtime=3
```

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora 15 `matchit.vim` comes in the `vim-common` package. Then add this to your `~/.vimrc` to get it working.

`source /usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/matchit.vim`

Then just press `Shift+5` (aka `%` ) to jump to the matching tag.

When editing an html file without the .html suffix, use the command:

`:set filetype=html`

to activate the matchit macro.

Answer (score 0):

Emmet. Just use [vim-emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim). It has some cool killer features. You just write `nav` and then `<ctrl + y> ,`(`ctrl` + `y`, then `,`) to do `<nav></nav>` automatically. `.myclass`, then `<ctrl + y> ,`, then you get `<div class="myclass"></div>`. And most of all, type `html:5`, then press `ctrl + y`, then `,`, and you get an html document set up.